# how to use dplyr() to subset observations based on the difference between two date

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a data frame (df1) with an ID variable and two date variables (dat1 and dat2).

I'd like to subset the data frame so that I get the observations for which the difference between dat2 and dat1 is less than or equal to 30 days.

I'm trying to use dplyr() but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df):

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),dat1=c("01/05/2017","01/05/2017","01/05/2017","01/05/2017","01/05/2017","01/05/2017"),dat2=c("14/05/2017","05/06/2017","23/05/2017","15/10/2017","15/11/2017","15/12/2017"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Desired outcome (df):

```
dfgoal <- data.frame(ID=c("a","c"),dat1=c("01/05/2017","01/05/2017"),dat2=c("14/05/2017","23/05/2017"),newvar=c(13,22))
```

Current code:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <-   df1  %>% mutate(newvar = as.Date(dat2) - as.Date(dat1))  %>% 
        filter(newvar <= 30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert to `Date` class before doing the subtraction

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(2:3, dmy) %>%
    mutate(newvar = as.numeric(dat2- dat1)) %>% 
    filter(newvar <=30)
```

The `as.Date` also needs to include the `format` argument, otherwise, it will think that the format is in the accepted  `%Y-%m-%d`.  Here, it is in `%d/%m/%Y`

```
df1 %>% 
     mutate(newvar = as.numeric(as.Date(dat2, "%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(dat1, "%d/%m/%Y"))) %>%
     filter(newvar <= 30)
#    ID       dat1       dat2 newvar
#1  a 01/05/2017 14/05/2017     13
#2  c 01/05/2017 23/05/2017     22
```